# Как подгрузить отдельный экземпляр формы (winforms) на панель (panel)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне необходимо подгрузить отдельный экземпляр формы (winforms) на панель (panel)? Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, путём создания собственного пользовательского элемента управления (UserControl). Была создана отдельная форма для ввода данных с элементами управления (textbox, label, button и т.д.), элементы управления расположены на панели (panel). После создания дизайна в проект был добавлен User Control (Windows Forms) и в дизайнер User Control перемещён макет созданной формы.
После проделанных манипуляций, можно легко добавлять свой элемент управления (полноценный интерфейс в отдельные tabControls или на другие элементы главной формы приложения).

Comment: А можете чуть подробнее расписать?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica добавил более подробное описание.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr NewParent);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            SetParent(f2.Handle, panel1.Handle);
            f2.Show();            
        }           
    }    
}
```

[image: form]

Но при таком подходе какие-то элементы Windows Forms могут вести себя неожиданно, так как предполагается, что Form - это окно верхнего уровня, которое не может лежать в элементе управления. Правильный способ отображения формы внутри формы - [MDI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications).